Paste URL In comment It auto turn to default title of page with link
Looking something like: when i comment a url on my wp post it will auto convert to its default title with hyper link.
example:
Right now when i comment URL https://www.google.com/ it looks like:
https://www.google.com/
I Need:
Google

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
